# Connect to Windows server and copy items from Jenkins slave Workspace to c:/wwwroot/ powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, hudson, powershell-3.0

I am using below PS script which will download Zip file from Nexus to Jenkins slave windows server.(Working as expected)
My another task is to copy files from Jenkins windows server location to another  windows server location.When I add this script in jenkins job i dont see any output nor errors. Please help me copy files which are zipped from Jenkins windows server to another windows server.

```
$ApplicationName="safenetws"
$clnt = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://localhost:8081/$($env:VERSION)/$ApplicationName-$($env:VERSION).zip"
$file = "D:\Packages\$ApplicationName-$($env:VERSION).zip"
$clnt.DownloadFile($url,$file)
$session = new-pssession -computername $($env:SERVER) -credential $($env:PASSWORD)
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application 
stop-WebSite -Name "SampleApp"
$items = $shell_app.NameSpace("D:\Packages\$ApplicationName-$($env:VERSION).zip\Content\C_C\Jenkins\workspace\Call\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\").Items()
$shell_app.NameSpace("D:\AppCode\wwwroot\SampleApp").CopyHere($items)
start-WebSite -Name "SampleApp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any file transfer servers, like FTP, I have used FTP for the same requirement, By using ftp plugin in Jenkins, you can configure the source (Jenkins work space) to destination (other windows server). when the build is running it will copy the code from one location to other.

Comment: Install the FTP server software in the other windows system / server, and then install the ftp plugin in Jenkins, in jenkins main configuration give the FTP server details. That's it. In your Jenkins Job just give a configuration.

Comment: @kamal-gadepalli-- Thanks for your solution but I need PS script to do this task.As Installing FTP in our servers is not allowed in our organization.